# Запуск java проекта из консоли

Tags: jar, cmd, java, консоль, dll

Нужно скомпилировать и запустить java программу из консоли. Программа использует библиотеки. Как указать расположение jar и dll файлов?

Comment: Почитайте, что такое CLASSPATH.

Comment: Запустите `javac` и получите список опций. В качестве отправной точки этого должно быть достаточно.